# How can I open a websocket connection outside of a context manager?

Tags: python, websocket, python-asyncio

This was raised in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42885563/why-cant-i-send-down-a-websocket-in-a-coroutine-called-by-a-coroutine/42885966#42885966), but I wanted to ask a new one about this specifically.

How can I connect to a websocket *without* using the context manager? I'm having trouble with the websocket closing by the time the coroutine that needs to use it is actually called.

```
ws = websockets.connect('ws://192.168.1.32:8765')
print(ws)
```

gives `<websockets.py35.client.Connect object at 0x0076CAD0>` rather than the `<websockets.client.WebSocketClientProtocol object at 0x04A91A70>` which I get from using the context manager. The `Connect` object doesn't have the `send` and `recv` methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
ws = await websockets.connect('ws://192.168.1.32:8765')
```

You can check out [`Client`](https://github.com/aaugustin/websockets/blob/992fc3a2794301ca4dbb94f9ce7801a4515e997d/websockets/py35/client.py#L11)'s source code to see how this works with the async context manager:

```
async def __aenter__(self):
    self.websocket = await self
    return self.websocket
```

To close the connection use:

```
await ws.close()
```

Keep in mind context managers are usually there to help you: You might want to change your code to use them instead of working around them.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: @Udi I would *love* to use the context manager - but it always closes the websocket connection before any coroutines can use it

Comment: Unless you await for then

Comment: even then, sadly.

Comment: @udi apologies - it's working now! There was an issue where that didn't work because of something else, but I've (hopefully) got it sorted now! If I can make it work in a separate thread, the full problem will be solved!